# xargs: Does `-n` and `-I` work with each other?

Tags: xargs

Input file `a.in`:

```
00
10 11
```

## Command 0

```
cat a.in | xargs -n 1 echo
```

## Output 0

```
00
10
11
```

## Command 1

```
cat a.in | xargs -n 1 -I '{}' echo '{}'
```

## Output 1

```
00
10 11
```

Why does `-n 1` lose its effect in Command 1?

Version: `xargs (GNU findutils) 4.6.0`

Comment: `-I` _"implies `-x` and `-L 1`."_... it's in the manual...

Comment: Just FYI-- it works as intended on the Mac BSD...

Comment: @don_crissti I saw that line but didn't see why `-L 1` should conflict with `-n 1`. Shouldn't it use the most strict limitation?

Comment: @Alex Hello, could you please post your Output 1 and xargs version?

Comment: @undercat Interesting. The latest version of GNU [findutils](http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/findutils/?C=M;O=D) is 4.6.0. Are you on a different platform then?

Comment: @Cyker never mind, it actually does not work. I need to think for a moment why

Comment: @Cyker according to the [source code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/xargs/xargs.c) `-i` excludes `-n` and `-l`, so they're incompatible by design it seems. Your best bet should be restructuring the input file, or doing that conversion on the fly before calling xargs

Comment: @Cyker The answer to your previous question answers this one as well (and the answer is effectively "no, they don't")

Comment: @undercat A nice find. The source code says `/* -i excludes -n -l.  */` but there's nothing about this in the manual. We've got an answer now even though I still can't understand why `-i` has to conflict with `-n` or `-l`. IMHO they do different things and without `-i` you have no way of putting the argument in the middle.